# Backup iPhone with dead screen on unknown Mac

Tags: iphone, backup, screen, lightning, data

My grandma´s iPhone 6 dropped from about 6 foot height, and the screen is absolutely dead. The iPhone itself seems to not be dead, but it´s locked and shows no visual indication whatsoever.

When pressing power button + volume down, I can force power it off. And using the power button, I can put it on again. I know that it´s on because the button vibrates upon "pressing" it (it´s vibration simulated).

Some of the data on it is not backed up in iCloud, and we need it.

Connecting it via Lightning to USB of a PC doesn´t do anything, nothing shows up in iTunes.

I had the intuition that it might work better on a Mac. So how can I pair / connect it to a previously unknown MacOS system via cable without unlocking it? What can we do to save data that would be lost on the phone otherwise?

Comment: Does the screen appear to respond to presses, even though there's no visual indication? Has the Phone ever been backed up on *any* computer before? If the answer to both of these is 'no' then you're a bit stuck. A third option… is it set to auto-backup to iCloud? If so, switch it on, plug it into a charger where it can see a known WiFi network, then leave it overnight & double-check from iCloud [on the web] in the morning.

Comment: The screen shows nothing at all. I doubt it had a real backup before.

Comment: If you cannot interact with the screen you cannot connect it to a computer at all. I think you'll have to get the screen fixed & hope it doesn't delete the data. I can't put this in an answer because I'm not certain how you'd do that.

Comment: iPhone 6 screens are very affordable and considering you *need* the data, less than 50 bucks should be worth a try. Changing a display is not that hard if you are somewhat familiar with electronics, iFixit has very good guides on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get the screen replaced first.
To connect to any computer for the first time, you need to "Trust" from the phone's screen & also unlock it with either TouchID or PIN.

Just replacing the screen should not affect data.

Comment: I see what you did here. Still waiting for the hat though :-)

Comment: It closed a hole… of sorts ;)) No Splunk as yet… still waiting